# PHP: Making an excerpt with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to make an excerpt of my content by matching this - [...]

```
$content_filtered = preg_replace("/<p>(.*?)\[...\](.*?)<\/p>/is", "<p>$1...</p>[...]<p>$2</p>", $item['pg_content_1']);
```

and then explode this [...]

```
$array_content = explode('[...]', $content_filtered);
```

to produce the excerpt,

```
$content_current = $array_content[0];
```

it works fine with when I use [...] like this,

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of[...] the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

it will produce something like this,

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of...
```

but if I put a white space before the [...],

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of [...] the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
```

then the dots will have a white space in the excerpt,

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of ...
```

how can I get rid of that white space?

I think I must to something with the regular expression in this line below but I don't know how!

```
preg_replace("/<p>(.*?)\[...\](.*?)<\/p>/is", "<p>$1...</p>[...]<p>$2</p>", $item['pg_content_1']);
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try capturing the whitespace before `[...]` and ignore it with `?:`

```
"/<p>(.*?)(?:\s*)\[...\](.*?)<\/p>/is"
```